# React Native: What is the best practice of define user-defined component?

Tags: react-native

```
  const ItemView = ({title, onPress, isActive}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={[styles.itemVTextBox,
        isActive ? styles.activeItemVTextBox : null
      ]}>
        <Text style={[
          styles.item,
          isActive ? styles.activeItem : null
        ]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

I see somebody write this code in the `render`.

I put this code between the `import` and `class define`, this code work too.

My code is like this:

```
   import React, {Component, PropTypes}   from "react";

import {
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  ListView,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
}   from 'react-native';

const ItemView = ({title, onPress, isActive}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={[styles.itemVTextBox,
        isActive ? styles.activeItemVTextBox : null
      ]}>
        <Text style={[
          styles.item,
          isActive ? styles.activeItem : null
        ]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);



 class MyOrder extends Component {

  render(){
   return (

    ...
     )
   }
  }
```

In my opinion, the `render` function will be executed a few times. If I put the code between the `import code` and the `class define` code, the code will be executed once.

Is my view right?

Do I need to put this user-defined code in a separate file?

In the separate file:

```
export default const ItemView = ({title, onPress, isActive}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={[styles.itemVTextBox,
        isActive ? styles.activeItemVTextBox : null
      ]}>
        <Text style={[
          styles.item,
          isActive ? styles.activeItem : null
        ]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

In the `container component`:

import ItemView from 'filePath' .

Is this practice is excellent?

Comment: If you want to reuse that code, wrap it as a component. But you will be calling this method as many times as the render method is called (I am asuming you are going to call that method inside render), what is leading you to think that code is going to be executed only once? 
And also, you are not following the standard proposed by Facebook Team.

Comment: I think that the render function will be executed a few times. So the const sentence will be executed a few times. If I put the defined code out of the render function, I think the defined sentence executed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button which is use in almost every component so make it a reusable component it could be a good practice if you always define separate folder for reusable components, below is one example:

```
//Button.js
import React, {Component, PropTypes}   from "react";

import {
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  ListView,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
}   from 'react-native';

const Button = (props) => {
    const { title,onpress,isActive } = this.props
    return ( 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={[styles.itemVTextBox,
        isActive ? styles.activeItemVTextBox : null
      ]}>
        <Text style={[
          styles.item,
          isActive ? styles.activeItem : null
        ]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default Button

//Main component

import Button from '@.../Button.js'

class MyOrder extends Component {

  render(){
   return (
    <Button title='login' isActive={false} onPress={this.loginButtonPressed()} />
    ...
     )
   }
  }
```

In Button.js, I have use jsx which is supported by react native and it look clean and good practice to implement like this.

Cheers :)